# What does Python Launcher do?

Tags: python

When download python from https://www.python.org/ and install it, I saw 2 apps installed, it is easy to see the purpose of IDLE but I am confused with the purpose of Python Launcher.
What does Python Launcher do ? When do I need to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For running Python on a mac start [at Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/mac.html)

Python Launcher allows you to run python scripts from the desktop.

The documentation says

> To run your script from the Finder you have two options:
>
> > Drag it to PythonLauncher
> >
> > Select PythonLauncher as the default application to open your script (or any .py script) through the finder Info window and double-click it. PythonLauncher has various preferences to control how your script is launched. Option-dragging allows you to change these for one invocation, or use its Preferences menu to change things globally.

From other Stack Exchange questions I think Python Launcher is not part of the python that Apple provides as part of the OS. But as you really should not use that python I have never tried to see.