# Why are there two apps called “python” and "python launcher" seperately?

Tags: macos, python

[image]Why are there ‘Python’ and 'Python launcher’? What’s the difference?

"Python launcher" is in `Applications/python 3.10/python launcher`

“python” is in the `MacintoshHD/library/frameworks/python.frameworks/resources/python app`

I can't run python files that use modules using 'Python launcher' but can by using the ‘Python' app.

And I can run a python file from anywhere, maybe Desktop or in a folder or anything by using 'Python launcher’.
But in the ‘Python' app, it either works on the Desktop or a specific place and is strictly not inside folders. (if I run, it's displaying an error as the directory cannot be found.)

The current version of python I use is 3.11
(I know only 3.10 is the most recent version. But I have accidentally downloaded a pre-release. It's the sixth of the seven alpha releases.)

Comment: These files do not come with macOS. How did you install these? More importantly [what problem do you face if you can run the scripts you need with one of the tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356262/5472)?

Comment: @bmike, what is the difference between the python and python launcher app? I didn't mean IDLE. and the 3.11 I downloaded from official python site.

Comment: Well neither of those apps you show are 3.11 and the  paths are not correct is it missing a / at the beginning and the second path has a space before app so is not a real path. Please cit and paste tyhe exact paths - and how did you install python 3.10

Comment: I downloaded python from the python website. I just want to know are there two different apps called ‘python launcher’ and ‘python’ seperately ?

Answer (score 1):

When Python is installed from [Python Releases for macOS](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/), apps for *IDLE* and *Python Launcher* are installed in a folder under *Applications*.

In *Ventura (macOS 13.x)* the `python` executable is placed in the system folder with its version, like so:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python`

*Python Launcher* allows users to run scripts from *Finder* instead of having to use *Terminal*. To use this, you can either:

- start the launcher app and drag scripts onto the launcher app's icon in the dock, OR
- associate `.py` files with the launcher app (which would run the script upon double-clicking the script in finder).

To find how to associate files with the app, do a search on:
*how to associate files with an app in macos*

**Note:**
[Python Releases](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) displayed with *universal installer* will work on both Intel and Mn (eg, M1, M2) Macs.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I ended up here after having the same question recently and ultimately came across [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) with a few simple commands that remove the "Python Releases for macOS"/"Python Launcher.app" Python versions while not touching the macOS default version in `/usr/bin/python3`.

Below is [the GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) quoted in its entirety at the time of writing for easy reference.

**Note that you must change the version number** in the below commands to match whatever version of Python Releases for macOS you have installed (you can find them by looking in the `/Applications` directory.)

> **1. DO NOT attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in `/System/Library` and `/usr/bin`.**
> **2. Multiple Python versions can coexist pacifically on macOS. So, uninstalling Python is purely optional.**
>
> To remove a different version, change `3.7` to the Python version you
> want to remove.
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 3.7"
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/*' -delete
> ```

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356243/what-does-python-launcher-do?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the [Python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) In short, "Python" is responsible for the `python` command in Terminal (Python.app is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/python`), while "Python Launcher" handles double-clicking Python files in Finder.

Comment: The Python documentation page you link to is very old and apart from sayin 3.9 (in 3.10 documentation) seems not to have been updated for many years (e.g. reference to ~/.Macos/Environment.plist which is pre Yosimite). It does explain PythonLauncher. But there is no explanation of Python.app

Answer (score -2):

The Python launcher gets automatically installed during the installation of Python with the .dmg file.
This launcher is actually bad i would recommend: uninstall Python and the python launcher.

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) in (case you havn't already) and install python by typing `brew install python`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Python Launcher app might be useful if you do everything from the Finder and not the terminal, you can drop python files on it to run them. 9As I don't install python from python.org I don't actually have it)

Comment: Making unsubstantiated statements like "this launcher is actually bad" is not helpful to the OP.  The launcher is an official part of the Python distribution.

Comment: OK if you are familiar with the terminal i don't think you would need the Python launcher